# Overriding nuget package name when using "nuget pack" with a visual studio project

Tags: msbuild, nuget, dotnet-cli, nuget-spec

I am currently generating nuget packages by passing in a csproj file instead of a nuspec file.  The problem is that I need to change the name of the nuget package to avoid conflicts with another project.

This is the command I'm running:

`"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" pack C:\VSTS\Agent\_work\1\s\src\MyProject\MyProject.csproj --include-symbols --include-source --output C:\VSTS\Agent\_work\1\a --no-build /p:Configuration=debug --include-symbols --include-source /p:PackageVersion=2018.10.11.3`

I tried appending the following to the command, but it seems to be ignored:

`/p:Id=ThisIsWhatThePackageNameShouldBe`

And also tried changing the assembly name in the project (but not the project name), and then doing this:

`/p:Id=$(AssemblyName)`

But this was also ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Something automatically added a `<PackageId>` element into the `csproj` file, and that was taking precedence.  I updated this value to what I want the package named and now it's working as expected.

I'm guessing the reason `/p:Id` argument was being ignored, was because it might have needed to be `/p:PackageId`, instead.